# Как добавить Font Awesome в кнопку через CSS

Tags: css, fontawesome

Мой код выглядит сейчас так:

```css
    .close_task {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        left: 15px;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        content: "\f00d";
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-xxzQGERXS00kBmZW/6qxqJPyxW3UR0BPsL4c8ILaIWXva5kFi7TxkIIaMiKtqV1Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <button class="close_task"></button>
```

Иконка не добавляется в кнопку. В похожих вопросах находил только варианты с псевдоклассами, а вопрос в том, как сделать это без них?

Comment: content работает только на псевдоклассах, так что никак

Comment: А другие варианты, как это реализовать можно, есть? Важно именно через css

Comment: нет, но если вы хотите сделать это для автоматизации, то лучше воспользоваться `JavaScript`'ом

Comment: Как раз и хотел сделать через css, чтобы в JQuery потом сделать подмену через toggleClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иконки [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.com) можно добавить несколькими способами:

1. C помощью элемента `i`:

   ```
   <i class="fas fa-ad"></i>
   ```
2. C помощью псевдоклассов before / after:

   ```
   div::before {
      content: "\f641"
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   }
   ```
3. Скачав SVG и добавив на страницу как изображение или в виде кода.

Для вариантов 1-2 нужно добавить саму библиотеку:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Comment: как сделать так, чтобы всегда иконка всегда одинаково отображалась на кнопке? При использовании псевдоклассов

Comment: Иконка при использовании вариантов 1-2 будет всегда зависеть от `font` настроек конкретного элемента.