# Как лучше сверстать иконку facebook?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Мне нужно сделать такой элемент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лучше сделать отдельный элемент сзади и на него наложить svg?

(я не знаю как это сделать, если знаете, покажите)

Или как я, просто задать padding(и) от svg?

```css
.facebook_logo {
  fill: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 11px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #2f3c4d;
  padding: 9px 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg display="none">
  <symbol id="facebook" viewBox="0 0 23.101 23.101">
  <path d="M8.258,4.458c0-0.144,0.02-0.455,0.06-0.931c0.043-0.477,0.223-0.976,0.546-1.5c0.32-0.522,0.839-0.991,1.561-1.406
                C11.144,0.208,12.183,0,13.539,0h3.82v4.163h-2.797c-0.277,0-0.535,0.104-0.768,0.309c-0.231,0.205-0.35,0.4-0.35,0.581v2.59h3.914
                c-0.041,0.507-0.086,1-0.138,1.476l-0.155,1.258c-0.062,0.425-0.125,0.819-0.187,1.182h-3.462v11.542H8.258V11.558H5.742V7.643
                h2.516V4.458z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="facebook_logo">
  <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
</svg>
```

Заранее большое спасибо

Comment: Если что масштабировать то твой вариант то чем не устраивает?Если конкретно вот такой логотип как у тебя то можно вообще найти шрифт какой написано f и прсто поверх написать f в div. Третий вариант делать той или иной картинкой.jpg gif png помоем других вариантов создание иконок и нет.

Comment: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 266.893 266.895"><path d="M252.164 266.895c8.134 0 14.729-6.596 14.729-14.73V14.73c0-8.137-6.596-14.73-14.729-14.73H14.73C6.593 0 0 6.594 0 14.73v237.434c0 8.135 6.593 14.73 14.73 14.73h237.434z" fill="#485a96"/><path d="M184.152 266.895V163.539h34.692l5.194-40.28h-39.887V97.542c0-11.662 3.238-19.609 19.962-19.609l21.329-.01V41.897c-3.689-.49-16.351-1.587-31.08-1.587-30.753 0-51.807 18.771-51.807 53.244v29.705h-34.781v40.28h34.781v103.355h41.597z" fill="#fff"/></svg>`

Comment: [тут есть и другие](https://worldvectorlogo.com/ru/downloaded/facebook-icon)

Comment: @Андрей Солуянов, лучше svg, он векторный

Comment: @Alexandr_TT в вопросе автора не присутствует не css не svg анимации, но Вы упорно ее добавляете (метки к вопросу). Зачем вводить в заблуждение тех кто ищет ответ на свой вопрос? При этом Вы удалили действительно **полезные** метки такие как "иконки" и "facebook". Чем было мотивировано ваше решение?

Comment: @Vasily метки `иконки` и `facebook` вы добавили сегодня. Почему-то давая свой ответ 15 дней назад вам тогда они не были нужны. Вдруг они вам понадобились сегодня. Я не знаю какие у вас появились сегодня соображения. Слова `иконка` и `facebook` есть в заголовке вопроса, поэтому кто ищет ответ по этим словам, тот найдет его.  Преимущественное право ставить метки принадлежит автору вопроса. Раз не были поставлены изначально эти метки, значит они не нужны автору. Я добавил метки, так как появились ответы именно  по этим меткам. У нас с вами равные права, после автора, но я это сделал первым

Comment: @Alexandr_TT то что Вы решили написать ответ, который включает в себя svg и css анимацию, внимание **не предполагает** что Вы можете поставить эти метки в вопрос автора. Если бы такое предполагалось на SO, то я бы мог написать тут ответ на C++ и поставить соответствующую метку в вопрос автора, который как можно заметить не имеет ничего общего с плюсами. (продолжение ниже)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT (начало выше) Я же Вам объясняю что вы можете ставить/менять теги, но эти теги должны относиться, внимание **к вопросу**, а не к Вашему ответу. Так же обращаю Ваше внимание на то что слова css, svg, и анимация так же легко ищутся по тексту вашего ответа, и, следовательно, исходя из Вашей логики не требуют того что бы быть продублированными еще и в метка. Похоже Вы не очень понимаете в чем их смысл, а просто ставите их для того что бы повысить Ваш внутренний рейтинг по ним

Comment: @Vasily Василий, поиграем в пинг-понг? Ваши метки также дублируют текст. Я также, как и вы, могу подозревать, что устанавливая метки, вы хотели поднять  свой рейтинг, путем поднятия редактированием топика. Я установил метки при написании ответа, вы сделали это только через 2 недели.

Comment: @Vasily что я ещё хотел сказать. Мне нравятся большинство ваших ответов, глубина ваших знаний, это не лесть, а искреннее восхищение, которое ежедневно выражается плюсами ваших ответов. Поэтому я попросил бы вас не заниматься никому не нужными спорами, которые отнимают время.  Знаете сколько копий сломано по поводу правильности установки меток и у нас и на англоязычном сайте. Сколько людей, столько и мнений. Единственное, что я вынес из прочтения этих споров и на чем мнения едины, что главное преимущество у автора вопроса. Автор снимет, заменит метки, я возражать не буду.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT У меня цель повысить качество локальной (Россия) ветки SO, в том числе это выражено и в правильной индексации, такой как постановка меток. Как Вы могли заметить я редактирую (стилистически) каждый из вопросов на который я отвечаю. С определенного периода времени я имею возможность создавать метки и сейчас я активно его применяю, обновляя по несколько вопросов на которые я уже отвечал, делая это на ежедневной основе. (продолжение ниже)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT (начало выше) Если у Вас сложилось мнение что я имею что то против Вас или Вашего ответа то это не так. При этом Ваши действия касательно меток провоцируют ненужные мысли что Вы это делаете с какой то одному Вам известной целью, а я со своей стороны стараюсь донести мысль что метки стоит ставить относительно вопроса а не ответа.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT (начало выше) Удаляя Ваши метки я руководствовался именно этим принципом, однако в целом я так и не понял почему были удалены те, которые добавил я (проясните этот момент). Если у вас есть опыт работы со структурированными данными, то, я предположу что Вы можете понять мою точку зрения относительно "меток для вопроса" и "меток для ответа" и то почему это разные вещи, по крайне мере на корневом SO

Comment: @Vasily `""в целом я так и не понял почему были удалены те, которые добавил я (проясните этот момент)".` потому что максимальное количество меток - 5 Вы удалили мои 2 метки и поставили свои 2 метки  Здесь нет к сожалению никаких структуированных данных, для этого нужно специализированное ПO В реалиях любой человек, может изобрести и поставить любую метку. В заголовках вопросов тоже нет порядка - просто бардак : Типо - 1.как сделать такую штуку 2. Почему это криво работает?  3.Почему блок вылазивает?  О каком структуировании данных можно говорить в этом случае?

Comment: @Vasily Я конечно правлю заголовки вопросов, на формулировки, реально отражающие смысл текста в вопросе, чтобы хоть немного навести порядок

Comment: @Alexandr_TT метки как раз и создают "структуру" в этом хаусе, поэтому желательно что бы они наиболее точно "описывали" и/или классифицировали вопрос, что впоследствии поможет лучше организовать данную базу знаний

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если Вы хотите добавить иконки, которые являются достаточно распространенными, то самым простым вариантом будет воспользоваться библиотеками типа [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com), которая позволяет выбрать способ вставки (тег `<i>`, Unicode, или SVG):

```css
i {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
```

*Более подробно о том как добавлять иконки FontAwesome я уже отвечал здесь:*

[Как добавить Font Awesome в кнопку через CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1152991/397819)

Comment: Подгрузка сторонних ресурсов такая-себе идея. Лучше воспользоваться svg, который можно хоть в base64 в css хранить

Comment: Из-за пары иконок социальных сетей тянуть огромный файл шрифта так себе идея. Оптимальнее сделать svg-спрайты. А букву "f" нужно брать непосредственно из брендбука Facebook: https://en.facebookbrand.com/. Из-за неправильного использования своих иконок Facebook вправе ограничить доступ вашему сайту к своей социальной сети, вплоть до полной блокировки.

Answer (score 11):

1. Можно использовать ваш вариант верстки иконки и даже сделать анимацию при наведении

```css
.facebook_logo {
    fill: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 11px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #2f3c4d;
    padding: 9px 14px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.facebook_logo:hover {
width: 22px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 27px;
background: dodgerblue;
fill:gold;
}
```

```html
<svg display="none">
            <symbol id="facebook" viewBox="0 0 23.101 23.101">
                <path d="M8.258,4.458c0-0.144,0.02-0.455,0.06-0.931c0.043-0.477,0.223-0.976,0.546-1.5c0.32-0.522,0.839-0.991,1.561-1.406
                C11.144,0.208,12.183,0,13.539,0h3.82v4.163h-2.797c-0.277,0-0.535,0.104-0.768,0.309c-0.231,0.205-0.35,0.4-0.35,0.581v2.59h3.914
                c-0.041,0.507-0.086,1-0.138,1.476l-0.155,1.258c-0.062,0.425-0.125,0.819-0.187,1.182h-3.462v11.542H8.258V11.558H5.742V7.643
                h2.516V4.458z"/>
            </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="facebook_logo">
    <use xlink:href="#facebook" ></use>
</svg>
```

Но всё же лучше использовать варианты иконок SVG с отдельными `path`, для контура логотипа и фона.
В этом случае иконка будет и респонсивной и возникают широкие возможности для анимирования.

*#1 Анимация рисования контура логотипа с последующей закраской*

```css
.container {
width:7vw;
height:7vh;
}
.back {
fill:#485a96;
}
.logo {
fill:#485a96;
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 266.893 266.895">

<path class="back" d="M252.164 266.895c8.134 0 14.729-6.596 14.729-14.73V14.73c0-8.137-6.596-14.73-14.729-14.73H14.73C6.593 0 0 6.594 0 14.73v237.434c0 8.135 6.593 14.73 14.73 14.73h237.434z" />

<path class="logo" stroke-dasharray="0,734" d="M184.152 266.895V163.539h34.692l5.194-40.28h-39.887V97.542c0-11.662 3.238-19.609 19.962-19.609l21.329-.01V41.897c-3.689-.49-16.351-1.587-31.08-1.587-30.753 0-51.807 18.771-51.807 53.244v29.705h-34.781v40.28h34.781v103.355h41.597z"  >
   <!-- Анимация рисования линии -->
<animate id="an" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click" dur="1.5s" values="0,734;734,0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   <!-- Анимация закраски линии -->
<animate attributeName="fill" begin="an.end" dur="0.8s" values="#485a96;#fff" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" /> 

</path>

</svg>
</div>
```

*#2 Анимация с использованием фильтра `saturate(10%)`*

```css
.container {
width:7vw;
height:7vh;

}

.container:not(:hover) {
  transition: 1s;
  filter: saturate(0%);
  -webkit-filter: saturate(0%);
  }
.container:hover {
  transition: 1s;
}
.back {
fill:#485a96;
}
.logo {
fill:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 266.893 266.895">

<path class="back" d="M252.164 266.895c8.134 0 14.729-6.596 14.729-14.73V14.73c0-8.137-6.596-14.73-14.729-14.73H14.73C6.593 0 0 6.594 0 14.73v237.434c0 8.135 6.593 14.73 14.73 14.73h237.434z" />

<path class="logo" stroke-dasharray="0,734" d="M184.152 266.895V163.539h34.692l5.194-40.28h-39.887V97.542c0-11.662 3.238-19.609 19.962-19.609l21.329-.01V41.897c-3.689-.49-16.351-1.587-31.08-1.587-30.753 0-51.807 18.771-51.807 53.244v29.705h-34.781v40.28h34.781v103.355h41.597z"  >
</path>

</svg>
</div>
```

**3# Анимация заполнения контура лого белым цветом**

Анимация реализуется за счет изменения атрибута `dy` SVG фильтра `feFlood`

```js
var svg1 = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  paint1 = document.getElementById('an_paint'),
  clear1 = document.getElementById('an_clear');
  
 svg1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
   paint1.beginElement();
}); 

   svg1.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
   clear1.beginElement();
});
```

```css
#container {
width:10vw;
height:10vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 266.893 266.895"> 
<defs>
 <filter id="filter1" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#485a96" />
      <feOffset dy="0">
      <!-- Анимация заполнения контура лого белым цветом       -->
      <animate id="an_paint" attributeName="dy" values="0;250" dur="0.5s" begin="indefinite" end="gr1.mouseout" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>  
          <!-- Анимация исчезновения закраски лого      -->
       <animate id="an_clear" attributeName="dy" values="250;0" dur="0.5s" begin="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>    
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  
 </defs>


<path class="back" d="M252.164 266.895c8.134 0 14.729-6.596 14.729-14.73V14.73c0-8.137-6.596-14.73-14.729-14.73H14.73C6.593 0 0 6.594 0 14.73v237.434c0 8.135 6.593 14.73 14.73 14.73h237.434z" fill="#485a96"/>

<path id="logo"  d="M184.152 266.895V163.539h34.692l5.194-40.28h-39.887V97.542c0-11.662 3.238-19.609 19.962-19.609l21.329-.01V41.897c-3.689-.49-16.351-1.587-31.08-1.587-30.753 0-51.807 18.771-51.807 53.244v29.705h-34.781v40.28h34.781v103.355h41.597z" fill="#fff" filter="url(#filter1)" >


</path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Блок социальных иконок в footer

В этом ответе блок социальных иконок выполнен на основе [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) и расположен в footer.
Добавлена стилизация иконок при наведении.

Добавлены ссылки для каждой иконки.

В принципе это готовая заготовка для макета веб странички, которую вы можете изменить, доработать по своему вкусу.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}


.header {
  background: #061D25;
  font-size:24px;
  color:#70726F;
  text-align:center;
  height:15%;
}
.content {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
footer {

  background: #061D25;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  height:5%;
}
footer a {
  color: #70726F;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #70726F;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
footer a:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #70726F;
}
footer a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rus">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
    </div>
    
<footer>
   
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```